# Implement browser back button on single page ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

Hi I am trying to implement the browser back button on my single page application I am using ajax to load the content. I can't figure out how I can achieve this I am really a newbie in frontend.

```
<script>
  $( function() {
  $( "#SearchItem" ).autocomplete({
  source: "{{ route('search') }}"
  });
  $("#SearchItem").keypress(function(e) {
  $('#SearchItem').addClass('loadinggif');
  $('#results').addClass('loadinggif');
  $('#results').show();
  $value=$('#SearchItem').val();
  $.ajax({
    type : 'get',
    url :"{{ route('phone') }}",
    data: {'SearchItem':$value},
    success:function(data){
      $('#results').html(data);
      $("#SearchItem").removeClass("loadinggif");
      $(".loading").removeClass("loadinggif");

         }
       });
      })
    });
  </script>
```

Here is where I am using above script!

```
  <div class="search mx-auto" style="width: 35%; margin-top:100px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SearchItem" 
       id="SearchItem" placeholder="Search..." >

  <!-- results displayed here -->
  <div class="results" id="results" style="margin-top:40px;">
  <div class = "loading"></div>

</div>
```

Please help me out!

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do, however it sounds like you should implement `pushState()` in your SPA, if you want the back button to function. Note that this involves writing your logic to work based on the current/previous page state; it's not a simple solution to create.

Comment: Back button on that page?  Isn’t that the same as simply reloading the page without a search?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Yes I am trying to implement pushState() , I came across something called jQuery bbq. But I really can't figure out how and where to put them in my SPA I am really new in ajax, and I need to figure out the sol for assignment.

Comment: @zipzit , what I am trying to achieve here is i need to loading  the '<div>' with results on clicking browser back I should be able to load the previous results!

Comment: Why not just save the search terms in an array and pop the last element, and search again? It wouldn’t be a real back button but instead perform a new search with old search terms, labeled as a back button.

Comment: What class is this homework for?

Comment: @zipzit please help me out its for grad school

Comment: Sure. 1) Learn how to create an empty array.  2) Push() string content into the array. 3) do this a few times... 4) learn how to pop() data off of the array.  5) You already know how to push a button and perform a search.  Create a different button and perform a search.   One suggestion. Use an open source tool for your code work, install a beautifier to help you keep content lined up to see what's going on.  Look at the indentations carefully. Keep it simple, have some fun. Good luck with your studies...